# MySQL updating Varchar Column with NULL

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql I need to update a `Varchar` column with a null value. I can use some query like this :

```
update books set Volume='NULL' WHERE BookId=5457
```

but it just updates the column with `NULL` as string
If I use this column data on mysql function [COALESCE](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) it returns the `NULL` as string not as real `NULL`.
My main problem is in this statement:

```
Select Title,COALESCE(Volume,PackId) From books where BookId=5457
```

I need the `COALESCE` to get the first `not null` and if I run my update with qoutes or not, it does not add real `NULL` to `mysql` row and `COALESCE` does not work properly  and returns  Volume not PackId

Is there a special syntax to do this?

Comment: You are telling it to be treated as a string with the quotes around it.

Comment: lose the single quotes - `update books set Volume=NULL WHERE BookId=5457 `

Comment: you are right , I have done it but after update it nothing adds to column.

Comment: i need to it be real `NULL` like columns have `NULL` as default value it is written `NULL`

Comment: @ganji: Have you tried the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
There is difference between `NULL` and `empty` in Mysql.
`NULL` means not set and empty means 0;

For my question when I create the table or alter it for adding new fields with `Varchar` type, I should permit Mysql to could set `Null` value to the field like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD `Volume` VARCHAR(25) NULL
```

or prohibit Mysql like:

```
ALTER TABLE `books` ADD `Volume` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
```

Now running

```
update books set Volume=NULL WHERE BookId=5457
```

will lead to setting real `NULL` that `COALESCE` function will understand it as `NULL`.

thanks guys for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove single quotes from Null:

```
update books set Volume=NULL WHERE BookId=5457
```

Comment: thanks , but the  `COALESCE` needs real `NULL` to act

Comment: Yeah...that's why I am setting real null in query.

Comment: Of course I tried.It sets nothing(I mean empty) to the field.Note:If we run same query in some fields with type `INT`  it sets `0`, not `NULL` . I want to set real `NULL`. Is it Clear?

Comment: You need to alter your table. you may have default value `0` for the column. Check your column properties.