# NULL insertion into a Column which has Varchar data type

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting some data into mysql database through php. The problem is that when I try to insert null value into a column it doesn't store like this :*NULL* and it actually saves NULL as text or when I remove the if statement from my php script it insert a free space in that column.
Here is my PHP code :

```
<?php

register();

function connectToDatabase(){
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pass","db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");
return $connection;
}


function register(){

$connection = connectToDatabase();
$OrgID = $_REQUEST['OrgID'];
$OrgName = $_REQUEST['OrgName'];
$OrgAddress = $_REQUEST['OrgAddress'];
$OrgPhone = $_REQUEST['OrgPhone'];


if($OrgName!=""){

    $check = mysqli_query($connection,"select count(*) from organization  where org_name='$OrgName'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check);
    if($row[0]>=1){

        print "old_user";

    }else {

        $result = mysqli_query($connection,"insert into organization (org_id,org_name,org_address,org_phone) values('$OrgID','$OrgName','$OrgAddress','$OrgPhone')");

        if($result!=""){
            print "ok";
        }else if($result==""){
            print "no";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

}else {
    print "null";
}

}

?>
```

And when I put the if statement to check for like this it saves the NULL as a text:

```
if($OrgID == '')
{
    $OrgID = 'NULL';    
}
```

And this is my Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `organization` (
`org_pid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`org_id` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
`org_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`org_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`org_phone` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`org_pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

Comment: because you have the null in single quores `'$OrgID'` is is a string.

Comment: BTW Learn about prepared statements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL updating Varchar Column with NULL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963707/mysql-updating-varchar-column-with-null)

Comment: @Jens but it is Varchar type and you can't remove single qoutes when it is varchar

Comment: You can if you mean null as a keyword

Comment: @Jens I did all the ways but it stores NULL like this : NULL 
and as you know NULL should be stored like this : *NULL*

Comment: Pay Attention. You Client Shows you itallic null, if the value in the database is null and in normal null, if it is the string null

Comment: @naqibloodin put this two statements on top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);` and report if this results in displaying any errors

Answer (score 0):

`null` should be set as:

```
$OrgID = null;
```

i.e. without quotes.